# fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: wireguard-go-bridge/libwg-go-arm64.a (No such file or directory

Tags: vpn, openvpn, wireguard

I have developed a framework which was working fine in debug mood also working in mobile phone but when I make a build for distribution compiler send me error

I have used Wireguard vpn use and its integration in app.

```
Makefile:68: warning: overriding commands for target `/Users/fitoutfit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FriendsVPN-guiobyjdevstmafjlnlacycwutee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Copy'
Makefile:65: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Users/fitoutfit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FriendsVPN-guiobyjdevstmafjlnlacycwutee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Copy'
Makefile:68: warning: overriding commands for target `of'
Makefile:65: warning: ignoring old commands for target `of'
Makefile:71: warning: overriding commands for target `/Users/fitoutfit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FriendsVPN-guiobyjdevstmafjlnlacycwutee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Copy'
Makefile:68: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Users/fitoutfit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FriendsVPN-guiobyjdevstmafjlnlacycwutee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Copy'
Makefile:71: warning: overriding commands for target `of'
Makefile:68: warning: ignoring old commands for target `of'
make: Circular /Users/fitoutfit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FriendsVPN-guiobyjdevstmafjlnlacycwutee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Copy <- /Users/fitoutfit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FriendsVPN-guiobyjdevstmafjlnlacycwutee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Copy dependency dropped.
make: Circular of <- /Users/fitoutfit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FriendsVPN-guiobyjdevstmafjlnlacycwutee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Copy dependency dropped.
make: Circular of <- of dependency dropped.
go build -ldflags=-w -trimpath -v -o "/Users/fitoutfit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FriendsVPN-guiobyjdevstmafjlnlacycwutee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Copy of OortVPN/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/FriendsVPN.build/Debug-iphoneos/wireguard-go-bridge/libwg-go-arm64.a" -buildmode c-archive
runtime/cgo
net
golang.zx2c4.com/wireguard/apple
rm -f "/Users/fitoutfit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FriendsVPN-guiobyjdevstmafjlnlacycwutee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Copy of OortVPN/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/FriendsVPN.build/Debug-iphoneos/wireguard-go-bridge/libwg-go-arm64.h"
lipo -create -output "of" OortVPN/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/FriendsVPN.build/Debug-iphoneos/wireguard-go-bridge/libwg-go-arm64.a /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/.prepared go.mod
fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: OortVPN/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/FriendsVPN.build/Debug-iphoneos/wireguard-go-bridge/libwg-go-arm64.a (No such file or directory)
make: *** [of] Error 1
Command ExternalBuildToolExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```